# Continuity of $f(x)=(xI-A)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $I_n$ be an identity matrix. If $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is not a eigenvalue of $A$, then $f(x)=(xI-A)^{-1}$ is a continuous function at $z$. Is that correct?

Comment: It will be a bounded linear transformation, and hence continuous.

Comment: @Dom: $f$ is not linear.

Comment: true, guess I was thinking about the map $f(x):\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$ but I suppose I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The coefficients of $(xI-A)^{-1}$ are polynomials on the coefficients of $xI-A$, which depend continuously on $x$. And since $z$ is not an eigenvalue, $\det(xI-A)$ is also continuous around $z$. Thus $(xI-A)^{-1}$ is such that each entry is, at $z$, a continuous function.